# Sincronizar base de datos de mysql

Tags: javascript, php, java, python, mysql

Tengo una base de datos en mi equipo local, y necesito que esten actualizadas o sincronizadas las tablas,columnas, indices y foraneas en otra base de datos remota.

En resumen, un algoritmo que compare tablas y columnas entre base de datos.

En este momento solo actualizo las tablas con ALTER, DROP, RENAME, MODIFY

¿Existe alguna librería o proceso que permita la comparación de tablas, y que esten sincronizadas?

Comment: Parece una necesidad muy especifica. Además, el algoritmo para lograr eso dependería de cuales son las bases de datos y como funcionan sus comandos. Es decir, muchas combinaciones posibles. Probablemente tengas que crearlo por tu cuenta. Por otro lado, pedir recomendaciones de librerias y otros recursos externos es uno de los motivos de cierre predefinidos, ya que las respuestas a dicho tipo de preguntas serían basadas en opiniones.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías ir guardando todas las instrucciones SQL relacionadas a modificaciones como Insert, Update, Delete en una tabla dedicada a conservar estos textos y con un campo para saber si ya se ha sincronizado con el servidor o no.

Luego crear un script para consultar los queries sin sincronizar y ejecutarlas en la base de datos remota.

Y para finalizar programar un cron para que cada x tiempo ejecute el script en el servidor local.

Saludos.